# How to add Authorization header in swagger using c#

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I installed swagger in visual studio 2015 web application and it's working good.But Authorization part is missing in that part how can i add authorization header in c# mvc web application Swagger.
Thanks in Advance.
http://prntscr.com/h1ohww.

Comment: Did you use Swashbuckle? If so did you look at [this page](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) in the section "Describing Security/Authorization Schemes"?

Answer (score 0):

1, Write a filter

```
    public class MyHeaderFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
            operation.parameters = new List<Swashbuckle.Swagger.Parameter>();

        operation.parameters.Add(new Swashbuckle.Swagger.Parameter
        {
            name = "Authorization",                
            type = "string",
            @in = "header",
            required = false // set to false if this is optional
        });
    }
}
```

2, Enable this filter in Swagger config in Startup.cs

```
config.EnableSwagger(c =>
         {
             c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "SwaggerUi");
             c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\{1}.XML", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly.GetName().Name));
             c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\{1}.XML", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Elephant.Entity"));
             c.OperationFilter<MyHeaderFilter>();
         })
         .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
         {
         });
```

Good luck!

Comment: I am using VS2017, depending on your Swagger version, the code can be a little bit different.